# Laragon downgrade PHP version to 7.2 and apache return error

Tags: laravel, apache, visual-c++, laragon

I installed a new PHP version in my Laragon from PHP 8.1 to PHP7.2 but it return an error about Visual C++ packages.
[image]

even though I have the package installed in my computer. [image]

Anyone know experience and solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while upgrading from php 8.1 to 8.2

Actually it accidentally shown the errors.

Reinstalling the visual c++ destitution doesn't work.

Change the php folder name works.

It fails because the php engine doesn's start correctly as it is not able to find some modules.

Also check the php path on your environment variables. Changing that will also fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the version of Apache from `2.4.41` from `2.4.54`

Comment: Are you suggesting this is a solution? Or are you experiencing the same problem as the OP?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35836913)